# Need a formula for the calculation of screen opacity where the starting point is at 0.1, and end point at 0.95

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, continuity

The title does not do it justice, but I have an app in which the screen opacity goes from 0.1 to 0.95 as you scroll down the page.

It will be 0.1 when you are at the top, and 0.95 when you are at the bottom, regardless of the screen size.

I have the following variables at my disposal:

- scrollTop: point which my scrollbar currently sits (changes as I scroll up and down, starts at 0)
- clientHeight (constant): height of the visible content
- scrollHeight (constant): height of all content, including what is not visible

My initial formula was as follows:

```
const variableOpacity = (0.95*clientHeight)/(scrollHeight - scrollTop)
```

Where, 0.95 is the maximum opacity the page is able to achieve. However, the issue is when my `scrollTop` is 0, I need the opacity to be 0.1, which will not happen in this case, so the formula is flawed.

Basically, I need a formula which will have a fixed start and end value of 0.1 and 0.95, respectively. Is this possible to be achieved? If so, what would it be.

In case my question is a bit convoluted, I have linked a sample app of the calculation working in action with my current solution and an indication of what is wrong: https://fltrx.csb.app/

[Full code sandbox if you want to see the code as well](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-sunset-kg5kj?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

`const variableOpacity = 0.1 + 0.85 * scrollTop / (scrollHeight - clientHeight)`

assuming that this is true:

`0 <= scrollTop <= scrollHeight - clientHeight`

and, even if it isn't, you can first calculate `scrollTop / (scrollHeight - clientHeight)` and then limit it to $[0,1]$ (i.e. make it $0$ if it is $\le 0$, make it  $1$ if it is $\ge 1$, check for division-by-zero etc.). That number, now being between $0$ and $1$, is mapped by a linear function $f(x)=0.1+0.85x$, which maps $0$ to $0.1$ and $1$ to $0.95$.